# Best way to handle statistic in database?

Tags: mysql, charts, statistics

I am working on an existing project (Angular / Symfony) and my need is to make a volumetric part in which I will display different graphics based on several criteria and having more filters, on the same page.

My database contains roughly 10 years of data and it is updated daily.

I would like to know what is the best way to consume this data and display it without degrading performance and above all by having a global view of all the changes made. (historical)

Should we use an archive system based on fixed dates for example each week/month .. ?

I saw that some are based on temporal tables and others on the partitioning of the DB.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Best way in terms of what? You need to define a clear criteria against which you and us can evaluate any solutions against! Also, you may want to consider using some kind a of a BI solution, rather than trying to build your own from the scratch.

Answer (score 0):

- If you will be purging "old" data, just `PARTITIONing`.  Else, partitioning is not likely to help performance.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint
- For faster access to summary data (eg, a graph of "last year's" data), build and maintain Summary table(s).  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables  Typically, there would be one row per day in such a table.  You may want finer-grained information for the latest month or something; we can discuss the details.
- Archive?  What is the intent?  We can discuss the pro and cons of options here.